# How delete unhide row filter in excel with VBS

Tags: excel, vbscript

have a good day, i have a question.
How is the way or what have i do for delete data unhide after aplicate a filter in a excel?
So, i did this filter.

```
Set parametros = WScript.Arguments
Set objExcel = GetObject(parametros(0)) 
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
Set dSheet = objExcel.Worksheets(parametros(1))
dSheet.Range("B1") = "RAZON_SOCIAL"
dSheet.Range("B1").AutoFilter 2, Array("COL S.A.", "COL S.A", "COL SA", "COL SA."),7
```

Now i need delete all data no filter after that.
how can i do it?

thanks for u time.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to delete complete rows or just cell content? Do you wish to delete the filtered data or everything?

Comment: I want to delete all rows that are unhide, so I need to keep only the data that I filter and delete the unfiltered

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub Filtering()
Dim x As Long, lRows As Long

    With dSheet
        lRows = .UsedRange.Rows.Count 'you can set this manually to your last row
        For x = lRows To 1 Step -1
            If .Rows(x).Hidden Then .Rows(x).Delete
        Next x
    End With
End Sub
```